# Is it possible to use portal-ext.properties variable in liferay-portlet.xml file?

Tags: xml, liferay, liferay-6

I am currently using liferay 6.1. I want to access portal-ext.properties in liferay-portlet.xml file. Is there any way to access it? I want replace version from ext properties dynamically.

**liferay-portlet.xml**

```
<header-portlet-css>/css/main.css?v={version}</header-portlet-css>
```

**portal-ext.properties code**

```
version=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible out of the box - if you check `PortletLocalServiceImpl._readLiferayPortletXML` you will see: there is no property interpolation.

And if you check `PortalImpl.getStaticResourceURL` you will see: a `?` in the URI of a CSS file will even drop all other generated parameters (like timestamp of last modification):

```
if (uri.indexOf(CharPool.QUESTION) != -1) {
    return uri;
}
```

So it was never intended to have any query parameters in the CSS URIs of a portlet.

If you really need the property, you can either change your build process to interpolate the version attribute during build time.

Or you create a *Hook* or *Ext Plugin* that overrides `PortalImpl.getStaticResourceURL` and does the interpolation for you. That is the more complex but better option, as it could add the Liferay specific parameters as well.

*But,* if you just want to increase a version flag to ensure that the file is not cached if you change something: There is no need to do that. If you add no question mark, like

```
<header-portlet-css>/css/main.css</header-portlet-css>
```

than Liferay will add a timestamp parameter automatically:

```
.../css/main.css?...&t=1234567
```

where `123456` is the modification time of your `main.css`. If you include some other files in the `main.css`, then you simply need to "touch" the `main.css` every time you change one of the other files.

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestion used ant base approach to change the url. I will write answer and blog soon to achieve cache-buster in liferay.

Comment: What do you mean with cache-buster? Something like that is already built into Liferay, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks sir for update but I am talking about browser cache suppose there is one file name abc.js and browser do not know version change and it is not reload some time. We have tested it in liferay.

Comment: As I said, that can't happen, as long as no `?` is added in your `liferay-portlet.xml`. Why? Because first the URL is `abc.js?t=(modification time)`, which is cached. When you change abc.js on the server, the URL is `abc.js?t=(new modification time)` which was not cached by the browser and will be reloaded. There is no difference to your version tag.

Comment: That is not happening some time and our client require to delete browser cache. With our code change we make sure on each release client browser forcefully take new release version of js , css Thank you very much for your assistant.

Comment: You should investigate further, why your client needs to delete the browser cache - maybe because the HTML page is cached itself? Because in that case even a version flag wouldn't help. And you should mark the answer as accepted.